# Why are we able to define curvature, torsion as linear operators instead of vector field ones?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

My question is why terms in differential geometry that are apriori complicated can be completely computed by linear tensors; details below.

Let $M$ be a manifold with a bundle $E$ and a connection $\nabla$, for simplicity we can take $E$ to be the tangent bundle.

Consider the two linear tensors:

1. Torsion; sending vector fields $X,Y$ to $\nabla_X Y - \nabla _Y X - [X,Y]$
2. Curvature: sending $X,Y,Z$ to $[\nabla_X, \nabla_Y](Z)$

Those both formalize intuitions that are expressed as local coordinates. Let us take a chart $U$, and say we have two tangent vectors $x,y$ at $0$.

1. We can either go $\epsilon x$ and then go the parallel transport of $\epsilon y$, or the other way around. The difference (the main term) is the torsion.
2. Draw the parallelogram of the vectors $\epsilon x$, $\epsilon y$, then parallel transporting $z$ along the two paths gives different results whose difference (the main term) is the curvature.

I am much more fond of the latter two explanations, being more geometric. But it's unclear to me how without a tedious computation (worse, a good explanation) one can show they really depend only on the vectors $x,y$, and not on vector FIELDS $X,Y$ or the underlying chart. At the moment I use the geometric intuition but prove statements via the vector field formulation.

Getting to the essence of my question, it is clear to me that given a connection, it is natural to consider the functor sending loops around a point to linear transformations (via parallel transport), but apriori this functor is complicated, and it turns out we can completely capture it using **linear** information at each poitn (I do agree that once you are able to locally approximate the functor, if you have a contractible loop you can integrate the curvature inside to obtain the total transport, but even locally I don't see apriori why there should be a linear notion).

I have also heard about fancier terms like Ehresmann connection, I can look into that if it gives a natural definition

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking? Do you want just a formal proof that the torsion and the Curvature are both tensors?

Comment: @ArcticChar I am asking how it is natural to invent it- what I would have tried to do if I was trying to invent it was drag a vector along a infinitesimal commutator, but this isn't a linear tensor, while dragging it both ways and comparing is.